# Dynamic import of data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get python to ask the user to open a file location, from where they would like the data to be read into a dataframe.

The code I am trying is:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import json
import gc
import os
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

Today = datetime.datetime.today()                                               # Set Today string to today's name
Today_day = Today.strftime("d")                                                 # Set Today_day to the date in the month (e.g. 21)

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and extension): ")       # Asks user for filepath of file to be used

    if not os.path.isfile(user_input):                                                                          # If filepath is not correct (e.g. missing or incorrect filename)
        print()                                                                                                 # Print a blank line
        print("I did not find the file at "+str(user_input))                                                    # Print that file was not found
        print()                                                                                                 # Print a blank line
        continue                                                                                                # Goes back to asking for a correct filepath

    else:                                                                                                       # If filepath is correct
        break                                                                                                   # Break out of while loop

#iFile = open(user_input,'rt')                                                                                   # Opens file, if present, in read only mode ("r"), specifying that it is a text file ("t")

gc.collect()                                                                    # Empty garbage collect
SIEBEL = pd.read_csv(user_input, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")                       # Get data from SIEBEL PSD2 extract
SIEBEL.fillna("", inplace = True)                                               # Replace null values with blanks
SIEBEL.sort_values("CIF", inplace=True)                                         # Sort dataframe by CIF values

print ()                                                                        # Print blank row
print (SIEBEL.dtypes)

print ()                                                                        # Print blank row
print ("SIEBEL extract contains:", len(SIEBEL.index), "rows")                   # Print number of rows in SIEBEL data
print ("SIEBEL extract contains:", len(SIEBEL.columns), "columns")              # Print number of columns in SIEBEL data

SIEBEL.drop(columns=["Eircode"], axis=1, inplace=True)                          # Drops oa column, in this case Eircode from the dataframe

print ()                                                                        # Print blank row
print ("SIEBEL extract contains:", len(SIEBEL.columns), "columns")              # Print number of rows in SIEBEL data

print ()
print (SIEBEL.dtypes)                                                           # Print all types in dataframe
SIEBEL.to_csv(r"C:\Users\LIDJ622\Desktop\SIEBEL_export"+Today.strftime("%B %#d")+".csv", index=None, header=True)   # Save the sorted file as a CSV to the desktop
```

However, when I try this, I get

> runfile('C:/Users/LIDJ622/Desktop/Test 1 increment.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/LIDJ622/Desktop')
>
> Enter the path of your file (Remember to include the file name and
>   extension): SIEBEL Extract 20k v1.csv Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/LIDJ622/Desktop/Test 1 increment.py', wdir='C:/Users/LIDJ622/Desktop')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/LIDJ622/Desktop/Test 1 increment.py", line 35, in
>   
>       SIEBEL.sort_values("CIF", inplace=True)                                         # Sort dataframe by CIF values
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 3634, in sort_values
>       na_position=na_position)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py",
>   line 250, in nargsort
>       indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

How can I get Python to ask where the user file is located, and then import it into the dataframe?

Edit: included full code and error message

Comment: Where is the error located? Line? Is there not more code?

Comment: It seems the error you have shown is not related to the code you have shared.

Comment: Edited to include code and error